# Misconfigured shell on remote host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

I installed the fish shell on a remote host through ssh. I later set it to my default shell through:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/fish
```

After logging out when I later tried to log back into the remote host I get the following error:

```
-fish: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre2-32.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 Connection to <ssh remote host> closed.
```

I have tried several different things to change the default shell back to bash or to remove the fish shell or even trying to modify the config file. This remote server is running Ubuntu 16.04.1 and is a virtual machine that I do not have physical access to. I have sudo access but not the login to the root user. All of the things I have tried so far have failed. I have tried the following:

```
ssh user@<remote host> "bash"
ssh -t user@<remote host> '/bin/bash'
ssh -t user@<remote host> 'sudo chsh -s /bin/bash'
scp new_config_file user@<remote host> /pathToConfigFile
```

None of these have worked so far and due to not having local access to this machine I was wondering if there are any other ways (other than re-imaging the virtual machine) to fix this issue and reestablish my connection.

Comment: This is an obvious question, but just to make sure it is not overlooked: Any other accounts on the VM with root or sudo rights?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there are no other accounts with sudo or root rights.